# Deploying to several environments on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I have an application that have several environments (all running in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk), namely, Production, Worker and Debug. Each environment have corresponding git branch that is different from master in some ways (like, configuration is changed and some code is deleted).

I use `eb deploy` to deploy the new version of application from its branch. It zips current git branch using `git zip` and sends the information to Amazon. Then it deploys to running instances.

The problem, however, is that deploying takes some time (about 5 minutes). Thus, between deploying, say, worker and production it have different code. Which is bad, because my changes might have change the queue protocol or something like that.

What I want is to be able to upload the information and to do its processing on all the environments, but not actually replace the code, just prepare it. And after I did it for all the environments issue command like "finish deploy" so that the code base is replaced on all the environments simultaneously.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a "blue-green" deploy and not do this in-place. Because your deployment model requires synchronization of more than one piece, a change to the protocol those pieces use means those pieces MUST be deployed at the same time. Treat it as a single service if there's a frequently-breaking protocol that strongly binds the design.

"Deployed" means that the outermost layer of the system is exposed and usable by other systems. In this case, it sounds like you have a web server tier exposing an API to some other system, and a worker tier that reads messages produced by the web tier.

When making a breaking queue protocol change, you should deploy BOTH change-sets (web server layer and queue layer) to entirely NEW beanstalk environments, have them configured to use each other, then do a DNS swap on the exposed endpoint, from the old webserver EB environment to the new one. After swapping DNS on the webserver tier and verifying the environment works as expected, you can destroy the old webserver and queue tiers.

On non-protocol-breaking updates, you can simply update one environment or the other.

It sounds complex because it is. If you are breaking the protocol frequently, then your system is not decoupled enough to expect to version the worker and webserver tiers, which is why you have to do this complex process to version them together.

Hope this helps!